# Upload file to Amazon storage with PyUpdater

Tags: python, amazon-s3, file-upload, upload, pyupdater

I am uploading a file to Amazon Storage though this does not seem to appear which is quite strange.  This is for pyupdater.  My only assumption is that for whatever reason it is either not loading the file correctly or not loading anything.

Output:

```
C:\Users\Hoxton\Pyupdater>pyupdater upload --service s3 setup.py
284 INFO: PyUpdater 2.5.1
[INFO] PyUpdater 2.5.1
289 DEBUG: Config Dir: C:\Users\D1\Pyupdater\.pyupdater
289 DEBUG: Config DB: C:\Users\D1\Pyupdater\.pyupdater\config.pyu
290 DEBUG: Config Dir: C:\Users\D1\Pyupdater\.pyupdater
290 DEBUG: Config DB: C:\Users\D1\Pyupdater\.pyupdater\config.pyu
291 DEBUG: Config Dir: C:\Users\D1\Pyupdater\.pyupdater
291 DEBUG: Config DB: C:\Users\D1\Pyupdater\.pyupdater\config.pyu
292 DEBUG: Config Dir: C:\Users\D1\Pyupdater\.pyupdater
292 DEBUG: Config DB: C:\Users\D1\Pyupdater\.pyupdater\config.pyu
293 INFO: Patch support enabled
[INFO] Patch support enabled
294 WARNING: Version file not found
[WARNING] Version file not found
294 INFO: Created new version file
[INFO] Created new version file
297 INFO: Creating new config file
[INFO] Creating new config file
310 DEBUG: found extension EntryPoint.parse('scp = scp_uploader:SCPUploader')
388 DEBUG: found extension EntryPoint.parse('s3 = s3_uploader:S3Uploader')
488 DEBUG: Setting config variable for region to 'us-west-2'
488 DEBUG: Loading variable profile from defaults.
489 DEBUG: Loading variable config_file from defaults.
490 DEBUG: Loading variable credentials_file from defaults.
491 DEBUG: Loading variable data_path from defaults.
491 DEBUG: Loading variable region from instance vars with value 'us-west-2'.
492 DEBUG: Loading variable profile from defaults.
492 DEBUG: Loading variable ca_bundle from defaults.
492 DEBUG: Loading variable profile from defaults.
492 DEBUG: Loading variable api_versions from defaults.
493 DEBUG: Loading JSON file: c:\users\D1\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\data\endpoints.json
495 DEBUG: Loading variable profile from defaults.
518 DEBUG: Loading JSON file: c:\users\D1\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\data\s3\2006-03-01\service-2.json
524 DEBUG: Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_post at 0x0000028510A6BC80>
524 DEBUG: Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function lazy_call.<locals>._handler at 0x000002850F9CA6A8>
538 DEBUG: Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x0000028510A6BA60>
538 DEBUG: The s3 config key is not a dictionary type, ignoring its value of: None
541 DEBUG: Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
542 DEBUG: Loading JSON file: c:\users\D1\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\data\_retry.json
543 DEBUG: Registering retry handlers for service: s3
543 DEBUG: Defaulting to S3 virtual host style addressing with path style addressing fallback.
544 DEBUG: Requested uploader: s3
544 INFO: Plugin: S3
[INFO] Plugin: S3
545 INFO: Author: Digital Sapphire
[INFO] Author: Digital Sapphire
```

**`Upload Complete`**

Steps taken:

```
SET PYU_AWS_ID=awdwada
SET PYIU_AWS_SECRET=dwadaw
SET PYIU_AWS_BUCKET=updater1
pyupdater settings --endpoints s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
pyupdater settings --urls
https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/updater1/?region=us-east-2&tab=overview
##Path to where update bucket is
pyupdater settings --company
updater1
pyupdater upload --service s3 setup.py
```

Full, relevant [code](https://pastebin.com/MRUzqzAz).

Comment: Region mismatch? Your program output mentions us-west-2 but your steps indicate us-east-2.

Comment: @systemjack Codes been heavily modified. Here's the original.  https://pastebin.com/1VvB7iGy  . I found I could set the ID and Pass in CMD but you can't SET Bucket name=dwad to get around in cmd.  I think this issue is also caused by not reading key and id correctly.